# Can't translate by vh/vw - I need this to be responsive, how can I convert the vh/vw to px?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am working on centering a semi-circle inside of another circle.

I would like this to be responsive, so changes in the browser keep the elements centered to where they need to be.

My idea is to have two semi-circle buttons on top of one another in another circle.

This is what I have so far.

```js
const dims = {height: '80vh', width: '90vw', radius: '7vw'};
const cent = {x: '50vw', y: '35vh'};




const svg = d3.select('#button-box');
const width = svg.attr('width');
const height = svg.attr('height');
console.log(width)


svg.append('circle')
    .attr('r', dims.radius)
    .attr('cx', cent.x)
    .attr('cy', cent.y)
    .attr('fill', '#0000a0')
    .attr('stroke', 'green')

const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${width /2}), ${height /2}`);

g.append('path')
    .attr('d', d3.arc()({
        innerRadius: 0,
        outerRadius: 100,
        startAngle: Math.PI / 2,
        endAngle: Math.PI * 3/2
    }))
    .attr('fill', 'whitesmoke')
```

```html
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jonsIdea.js"></script>

<div class="jonsIdea">
        <div class="canvas">
            <h1>Please select your businesses</h1>
            <svg id='button-box' width="90vw" height="80vh">

            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Could anyone please help me in converting my vh/vw width/height params into pixels dynamically so I can center and adjust the semi circles? Thanks

Comment: Why did you used library to create circle? Don't you think it is possible using css only?

Comment: I need to use the library in order to make the semi-circle.

I could copy and paste a semi-circle in and change it with CSS.

Would that work do you think?

Comment: Circles and semi-circles (many other shapes also) are pretty trivial with css alone. You might want to consider that as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want have somethink like this? Than you can add a click-event-listner to each path.

**update:**

now the example have onclick event.

```js
document.getElementById("idPathRed").onclick = (f => console.log('click red'));
document.getElementById("idPathGreen").onclick = (f => console.log('click green'));
document.getElementById("idPathBlue").onclick = (f => console.log('click blue'));
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;   padding: 20px;   justify-content: center; align-items:center; background-color: lightblue">
<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="116px" height="116px" viewBox="0 0 4800965 4800965">
                <path id="idPathRed" style="fill:red" d="M2400483 2400483l2393194 0c0,1321728 -1071466,2393194 -2393194,2393194l0 -2393194z" />
                <path id="idPathGreen" style="fill: green" d="M2400483 2400483l-2393195 0c0,-1321729 1071466,-2393195 2393195,-2393195 1321728,0 2393194,1071466 2393194,2393195l-2393194 0z" />
                <path id="idPathBlue" style="fill:blue"  d="M2400483 2400483l-2393195 0c0,1321728 1071466,2393194 2393195,2393194l0 -2393194z" />
            </svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bergi, thank you so much for your solution. I have pivoted to using CSS for this and have something quite simple now. Could you tell me how you went about making this? Thank you again.

Comment: Hey, you can write svg code yourself [link](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp) or use Programms like Coreldraw or Inkscape(free) and export your graphic to svg... If it solve your problem, please mark my post as answer!